# Changing the status bar color for Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-toolbar

I've read a bunch of different posts regarding this issue but have not found anything that works. I want my app to be compatible with Android 5.0 and older versions.

For Android 5.0 I am trying to implement the status bar color change. I know this won't work for older versions though. But when I run my app on the GenyMotion VM supporting 5.0, the status bar color doesn't change to the `colorPrimaryDark`. It also doesn't change color in the `xml` preview section of Android Studio.

Here are the relevant files:

res\values\styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

res\values-v21\styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

res\layout\toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

res\layout\activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tBar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Possible issues:

I think I may have added some unnecessary items in `res\values-v21\styles.xml`.
Plus I thought I was supposed to make the `parent = "@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`" but other tutorials have it as `Base.AppTheme`. Also possible that I need to add more code in `MainActivity.java`

Can someone please help? This whole topic has me very confused.

Thanks

Comment: Since you are already defining you app color in AppTheme.Base, you don't need to define them again on styles-v21, you could actually just leave styles-v21 empty and it should work. I'm sure your problem is that you are overriding the values you already stablished

Comment: Unfortunately still does not work...

Comment: What are you using as the application theme?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try changing the status bar color programmatically: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple program. you can do it programatically

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can find very stupid but in my code i had that experience and your v-21 style.xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

also you have to didn't define status bar color in lollipop automatically its created from Dark Primary Color. You can try this code

Answer (score 0):

It'll not change status bar color if you have

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

removing this line from your app theme is the only i have found yet to change status bar color t runtime using setStausbarColor().

And still if you want to change color with android:windowTranslucentStatus then this tutorial i found useful so far [link](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx).